# How do I output a YouTube video with EXT:blog from a page's resources in Fluid?

Tags: youtube, typo3, blogs, fluid, typo3-8.x

In the context of `EXT:blog` (which may or may not be relevant) on TYPO3 8.7 I added a YouTube video under *Resources > Files > Media > Add media by URL*. This results in a reference to a `.youtube` file.

Within `List\Post.html`, a Fluid template which overrides `EXT:blog`'s `Post.html`, I get access to the `post.media` array. `post.media` contains a `FileReference`. When rendering that using `<f:image src="thatreference.uid" treatIdAsReference="1" .../>` I do get the video's thumbnail.

How do I determine whether a `post.media` entry refers to a YouTube video and how do I render that video instead of the thumbnail image? I could not find any useful properties on that `FileReference` (such as media type or YouTube video ID) yet. Do I need to go another route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media, including images and videos, can be output using the [f:media ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/MediaViewHelper.html):

```
<f:media file="{thatreference}" width="400" height="375"/>
```

To determine the resources media type use `{thatreference.originalResource.originalFile.type}`. A value of 4 stands for video, 2 stands for images:

```
<f:if condition="{thatreference.originalResource.originalFile.type} == 4">…</f:if>
```

The original YouTube URL can be read from `{thatreference.originalResource.publicUrl}` and various other properties such as preview dimensions (useful for calculating aspect ratio) from `{thatreference.originalResource.properties}`.

Comment: I decided to add my own, somewhat more complete, answer, but the references to `f:media` pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<f:media />` which outputs all media types including youtube videos

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. For more details [f:media](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/MediaViewHelper.html).

You can get your file path like this `{thatreference.originalResource.publicUrl}`

```
<f:media file="{your file path}" width="400" height="375" additionalConfig="{loop: '1', autoplay: '1'}" />
```